# Splitting AAC audio channels via MFT

Tags: ms-media-foundation, aac

I'm creating an MFT to handle AAC streams with more than 6 channels (as the AAC Decoder in Windows can only handle 6 maximum).  I'm planning to still use the Microsoft AAC Decoder but I will first take the AAC stream and split the channels into groups of 6 before passing them to multiple instances of the AAC Decoder.

Does anyone know whether is is possible?  I've been looking at the AAC spec and I see it has ICS sections for each channel (I'm assuming all channels are independent), so I was hoping I could read the bytestream, extract the ICS's and then generate new streams to pass on to the AAC Decoder.

Before embarking on this I was wondering if someone has tried this before or can tell whether this is even possible in theory?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "group of 6", which AAC can carry 6+6 for example?

Comment: Sorry, I meant if I have an MP4 that carries an AAC track with 16 audio channels, I could split it up into 6, 6, and 4 channels and use 3 Microsoft AAC Decoders to decode those channels into PCM/Float channels.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can "split" AAC bitstream into "groups of 6 channels". This is not how things are designed to work in first place. Even though AAC offers support for [up to 48 channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding) which is something I myself can't recall seeing, the bitstream is to be decoded before it can be split in decoded domain. Microsoft's stock codec is limited to support 5.1 audio and so it is unable to handle other channel configurations within a track. You can have multiple tracks with 5.1 audio on each and in this case the stock decoder is applicable.

To support AAC encodings that stock decoder cannot handle you will have to provide an alternate AAC decoder built from scratch (with no relation to existing stock MFT, that is) and packaged as a new separate MFT. Or you need to prepare a media file in a special way that every single audio track is suitable for stock decoder.

Comment: Thanks Roman, that makes sense.  I think I will investigate Opus as it seems better suited to supporting multiple independent audio channels (using mapping family = 255 option) and the c++ decoding lib is accessible.   Thanks again!

Comment: @AndrewRH You can encode channels separately, no matter which codec you're using.  I think the point here is that these codecs are normally taking advantage of the fact that the channels often have similar content.  If you want separate tracks in the same stream, encoded/decoded separately, you'll usually be wasting bandwidth.